# Connect PHP scripts remotely

Tags: php, remote-server, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to use some PHP scripts but when i try to use them it gives me an error

```
("this page isn't working")
```

I can see the PHP files in the navigator this way http://public-ip/folder/  but then when i tape http://public-ip/folder/script.php  I get the error

If it helps the same error appears if i access it with local ip 
`192.168.1.24`.

It is an Ubuntu Server, XAMPP installed with PHP 7.0, Apache2, phpMyAdmin, MySQL (i have permission),...

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have a firewall apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Does the script work on a different server? This error message could be anything...

Have a look in your php system logs for more information.

/var/logs/